# Minimal OpenSSL build for Boost.Beast

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm working on an application that uses Boost.Beast and TLS connections. As part of my application's build process, I need to compile OpenSSL into a static library. OpenSSL takes a long time to compile and I'm trying to reduce the build time. I see that OpenSSL's `config` script has many options for disabling parts of the library.

Is there a list of all the OpenSSL options that I can safely disable, and still be able to use TLS connections via Beast?

The reason I'm not using the preexisting shared library is that I want to be able to deploy a portable, self-contained binary to a target device other than my development PC.

For convenience, here is the link to the OpenSSL document listing config options: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an exhaustive list.

A good start are the build options for embeded systems like openwrt.
https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/package/libs/openssl/Makefile

or buildroot.
https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/libopenssl/libopenssl.mk

Comment: OpenWRT indeed looks like a good starting point. It probably needs more OpenSSL features than a simple web server, though. Thanks for making me aware of Buildroot! [relevant_to_my_interests_cat.jpg]